# Connection string for remote SQL server 2008 without SQL Management Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, deployment, database-connection

I know its a classic problem, but I am too novice to even comprehend the basics (sorry). I have this ASP.NET "Website" with databases (SQL Server 2008), which I am trying to deploy on a Remote Host Server (HostGator) using WebSite Copy tool of VS 2010.

In VS 2010, I could grab the Connection string directly through the "property" of the database, which turned out to be:

> Data
>   Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\myName\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2010\WebSites\Experiment\App_Data\data.mdf";Integrated
>   Security=True;User Instance=True

Now, I know that a website called http://connectionstrings.com/ exists, but its too overwhelming for me at first glance.

My current connection string:

> Data
>   Source=domainName.com\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\inetpub\vhosts\domainName\httpdocs\Experiment\App_Data\data.mdf;Integrated
>   Security=True;User Instance=True

I am pretty sure, that this is wrong as its giving me the classic error of:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server..

But I don't know how to fix it. Where to start looking, how to initiate, how to get the parameters required to build the connection string. How to find the path of the `AttachDbFilename` ? Can you please help?

I believe, that connection string is the only parameter which needs to be modified. If there's something else, then please suggest?  Also, I keep coming across the usage of SQL Management Studio to make things work, I don't have that, so is it hard to accomplish this without it?

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify a directory relative to your own machine. 
Change AttachDbFilename to

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|data.mdf
```

The specifics for `Data Source` should be given to you from your hosting company, as well the security model (probably you need to use a specific user)

You can download SqlServer Management Studio Express from [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593)

Comment: thanks for help. But what would I set DataDirectory to? Is that something I need to ask hosting company too? Or the path which I mentioned was correct? Because I kind of guessed with that one. How to get that path in the first place? Thanks.

Comment: No, DataDirectory is a special placeholder that will be resolved directly by the ASP.NET engine. You should only put the MDF file in your website App_Data folder

Comment: Thanks, so I got info from them. They gave me the IP Address of the Server. Is that enough? or do I have to use the instance name as well? such as "IP_Address\SQLEXPRESS" ? Thanks. || Another question, I just copied the database to the remote server, why/how would I need/use the security model? as in the database username and password? how did this come from? How do I set/get this? Sorry for further questioning.

Comment: The IP address should be enough if they don't give you any other indication about ports. You don't need to specify the instance name because you are served by their main server (probably a full sqlserver installation). The user and password should be given by them together with the IP. If not you could ask them what is their policy.

Comment: thanks. Quick question, when I used MySQL with PHP, even while working locally I had to use username and password to access database and I set another credentials(given by Hosting folks) when I created database in the web server. In current case, I never used username/password locally, so when I copy my database/tables etc to the hosting space/webserver(in the App_Data folder)using the website copy tool; where exactly does username and password come in then? or its not required? or which aspect am I really missing? what exactly am I supposed to do after copying the *.mdf. Thanks again.

Comment: When you work locally, you are authenticated by your Windows Login token that is passed  to SqlServer (`Integrated Security=Yes`), but when your database reside on a hosting server you cannot use this kind of security and need to pass `User ID=user;Password=pass` [See this link for detailed infos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669066(v=VS.110).aspx)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15642/discussion-between-dev-dreamer-and-steve)

Answer (score 0):

Man,

What do you think about [HttpServerUtility.MapPath Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx). It returns the physical file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path on the Web server.

[]'s

Answer (score 0):

When you get your hosting. They will provide the connection string for you. like this

```
  <add name="ConnectionStringName" 
       connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Database=YourDatabaseName;Uid=YourUserNameForDatabase;password=yourpassword;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Let me know, if you need more help

Comment: thanks for help. My connection string is in C#, and not in web.config. Is that a problem? Because I never used the "providerName" clause. Is it important in C# too? Also, is there any specific reason for setting "Data Source" as localhost? or is this the right parameter?

Comment: localhost is provide to me by hosting provider.